# PHP ExactTarget API returns Empty Response when trying to connect

Tags: api, marketing-cloud, soap-api, php

I'm just trying to do the basic connection to the service, but I'm getting the following message on the page:

```
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

This is the code I'm using.

```
$includeDir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/');
$path = ini_get('include_path');
$path = $includeDir . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path;
ini_set('include_path',$path);

require('exacttarget_soap_client.php');

$wsdl = 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl';

try {
    @$client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl,array('trace'=>1));

    $client->username = '<username hidden>';
    $client->password = '<password hidden>';

    $param = new ExactTarget_VersionInfoRequestMsg();
    $param->IncludeVersionHistory = True;
    $results = $client->VersionInfo($param);
    var_dump($results);
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Just to make sure I wasn't missing an include or anything I commented out

```
$results = $client->VersionInfo($param);
var_dump($results);
```

When I do that and just echo out something it works fine. It's when it tries to execute the `VersionInfo` call that it seems to break.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the problem was I didn't have mcrypt installed. I thought I had, but nope. That was it.